# xcode thowing NSInvalidArgumentException internal error

Tags: xcode4

Xcode recently started to throw an internal error from CoreFoundation when I debug an app. If I click continue it seems work. Is this ok? Is there a known workaround? (reload reboot don't seem to help)

[image]

Comment: File bug reports with Apple when Xcode crashes. SO can't really help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing all of my break points and adding them back again solved the problem.